# ¿genera algun conflicto que yo use archivos javascript en un proyecto de angular?

Tags: javascript, typescript

mi pregunta viene a cuestion de que yo logré conectar una base de datos oracle pero solo con js, y estoy usando angular que utiliza typescript, ¿generaría algun conflicto cuando yo tenga que hacer peticiones de la base por medio de typescript si la conexión la tengo con javascript?

Comment: El typescript al final se transpila ("se convierte") a JavaScript para que el navegador lo pueda entender así que en principio no.

Comment: Conflictos no, pero yo refactorizaría tu código y lo tendría en un servicio de Angular, sinceramente. Además, nadie te impide escribir JS dentro de dicho servicio... al fin y al cabo como ha mencionado David, el TS se transformará en JS para que lo ejecute tu navegador!

Comment: TypeScript al final es un superconjunto construido por encima de JavaScript así que pordrías hacer como dice Benito y encapsularlo en un servicio y puedes usar un archivo `.ts` escribiendo únicamente js puesto que al final se convierten a lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

Typescript es un superconjunto de Javascript. Esto significa que todo Javascript válido, es también Typescript válido.

Por tanto puedes tomar tu fichero Javascript, renombrarlo y cambiar la extensión desde js a ts y todo seguirá funcionando<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup>: Es posible que uses ESLint o algún analizador que se queje de la falta de tipado, pero todo debería funcionar.